# Processor Upgrade HP Elite M9510F

Tags: cpu, upgrade

I have an HP 9510F that uses the ASUS IPIBL-LB MB.  It ships with an Intel Q8200 Quad Core processor but it does not support virtualization.   Specs for the board from HP (ASUS does not list this OEM board) do not show support for the Intel Q8200 it ships with (obviously incorrect) but only these

•   Supports the following processors: 
o   Intel Core 2 Quad (Yorkfield core) Q9xxx 
o   Intel Core 2 Duo (Wolfsdale core) E8xxx 
o   Intel Core 2 Quad (Kentsfield core) up to Q6600 
o   Core 2 Duo E6x00 (Conroe core) up to E6700 
o   Core 2 Duo E4x00 (Conroe core) up to E4400
Can this MB support the Q8400 or will it only support the indicated Q9xxx series?  Naturally HP is little help here.

Specs are located here[HP/ASUS MB specs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01324212&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=3876397&lang=en#N932)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the socket/FSB specs, it seems like this board should support the Q8400 just fine.

Comment: Works like a charm!